# User doing sort of a list UI in JAVA at the same time

Tags: java, concurrency

We will have a list UI that a user can sort the records. What if the user A sort the list and User B sort the list at the same time? I am thinking to prevent a confusion upon saving the sorting. Because if User B sort Z-A for example and User A sort it A-Z. Then user B saved it first. User A will get confused because the sorting he made will not be reflected.

Comment: If you're not keeping user A's preferences separate from user B's preferences, and they're doing things to the same data, this is unavoidable.

Comment: How are these records accessed by each user’s UI?

Comment: it was saved in DB and retrieve whenever the form is open by a user, with a field sortNumber. for example the Entry was put on the top. the sortNumber will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add a user preference from both users, so that they won't affect one another's settings. Correct me if I'm wrong, in my practice, I store my user preferences from the database or saving them from a JSON file.

Comment: Are you using a database? So I can better understand your point. As I might misunderstand you.

Comment: the list will be saved in DB and retrieve whenever the form is open by a user, with a field sortNumber. for example the Entry was put on the top. the sortNumber will be 1

Comment: have you tested or create this already, or you're just asking if it's possible. Because if not yet, it's impossible for both users to affect one another's sorting of their list.

Comment: i am just making a scenario.. For example User A doing the SORT, then saved it while the other User did his sorting and overwritten the sorting that was made by User A in a matter of seconds. When UsER A refreshed the sorting, he will be confused why the sorting he did was changed.

Comment: how about adding another column to the user, then save the settings in the user's table, instead of saving the SORT in the table which they're trying to use. So even both users change their SORTING at the same time there won't be any collisions between the two.

Comment: I recommend that you should try what we are currently discussing so that you can better analyze the problem.